# how to copy all files from host to C disk drive vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to copy all files from the hosting to a local drive by the following code:

```
        Dim websiteUrl As String = "https://mada.net/sys-23/"
        Dim localFolder As String = "D:\MyFolder\"

        Dim downloader As New WebClient()
        downloader.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Dim htmlContent As String = downloader.DownloadString(websiteUrl)

        ' Parse the HTML to extract the URLs of the files.
        Dim regex As New Regex("<a href=""(.*?)"".*?>.*?</a>")
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(htmlContent)

        For Each match As Match In matches
            Dim fileUrl As String = match.Groups(1).Value
            If Not fileUrl.EndsWith("/") Then ' Skip directories.
                Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl)
                Dim localFilePath As String = Path.Combine(localFolder, fileName)
                downloader.DownloadFile(websiteUrl & fileUrl, localFilePath)
            End If
        Next
```

but I got an error:
System.Net.WebException: 'An exception occurred during a WebClient request.'

what is the problem?

Comment: on which line do you get the exception? does it have an inner exception?

Comment: in line:                     downloader.DownloadFile(websiteUrl & fileUrl, localFilePath)

Comment: so this exception has nothing to do with your question- you just cannot access this URL... I'm getting some "Security Risk" error when I try to reach it in my browser.